# How to translate data from json file to dates of week in php?

Tags: php, arrays, json, wordpress

currently i have this set of data fetched from API

```
array(7) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    ["LocationId"]=>
    string(36) "da4f4609-d76b-41f0-a517-ca525d71c914"
    ["DayId"]=>
    int(4)
    ["StartTime"]=>
    string(19) "2019-04-15T06:00:00"
    ["EndTime"]=>
    string(19) "2019-04-15T22:00:00"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(4) {
    ["LocationId"]=>
    string(36) "da4f4609-d76b-41f0-a517-ca525d71c914"
    ["DayId"]=>
    int(1)
    ["StartTime"]=>
    string(19) "2019-04-15T06:00:00"
    ["EndTime"]=>
    string(19) "2019-04-15T22:00:00"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(4) {
    ["LocationId"]=>
    string(36) "da4f4609-d76b-41f0-a517-ca525d71c914"
    ["DayId"]=>
    int(5)
    ["StartTime"]=>
    string(19) "2019-04-15T06:00:00"
    ["EndTime"]=>
    string(19) "2019-04-15T20:30:00"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(4) {
    ["LocationId"]=>
    string(36) "da4f4609-d76b-41f0-a517-ca525d71c914"
    ["DayId"]=>
    int(2)
    ["StartTime"]=>
    string(19) "2019-04-15T06:00:00"
    ["EndTime"]=>
    string(19) "2019-04-15T22:00:00"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(4) {
    ["LocationId"]=>
    string(36) "da4f4609-d76b-41f0-a517-ca525d71c914"
    ["DayId"]=>
    int(6)
    ["StartTime"]=>
    string(19) "2019-04-15T08:30:00"
    ["EndTime"]=>
    string(19) "2019-04-15T19:00:00"
  }
  [5]=>
  array(4) {
    ["LocationId"]=>
    string(36) "da4f4609-d76b-41f0-a517-ca525d71c914"
    ["DayId"]=>
    int(0)
    ["StartTime"]=>
    string(19) "2019-04-15T08:30:00"
    ["EndTime"]=>
    string(19) "2019-04-15T19:00:00"
  }
  [6]=>
  array(4) {
    ["LocationId"]=>
    string(36) "da4f4609-d76b-41f0-a517-ca525d71c914"
    ["DayId"]=>
    int(3)
    ["StartTime"]=>
    string(19) "2019-04-15T06:00:00"
    ["EndTime"]=>
    string(19) "2019-04-15T22:00:00"
  }
}
```

For the DayId, 0 is Sunday, 1 is Monday and so on. The end result is something like this

Sat, Sun: 08:30 AM - 07:00 PM
 Mon - Thu: 06:00 AM - 10:00 PM
 Fri: 06:00 AM - 08:30 PM

Currently, I have to hard code all the dates and then pull the times only from the JSON. I wonder someone can help me:

1) Translate dayID -> Monday, Tuesday, etc...

2) Display the data afterward the same way that I hard code the dates.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Do you want dayId would be only Days name or Sat, Sun: 08:30 AM - 07:00 PM  like that ?

Comment: Hi Hashemi, thanks for looking into this. I want to be able to translate dayID to days name yes. So, if i have dateID = 0 from the json, I can somehow translate that to Sunday and then display Sunday on the website.

Answer (score 0):

For your first question, you could simply have an array of days:

```
$days = [
    'Sun',
    'Mon',
    'Tue',
    'Wed',
    'Thu',
    'Fri',
    'Sat'
];

$day = $days[0];
```

For your second question, for the dates themselves, if these are the dates you receive from your API, you can transform them by using `DateTime`:

```
$startTime = new \DateTime($data['StartTime']);
$endTime = new \DateTime($data['EndTime']);

echo $startTime->format('h:i A') . ' - ' . $endTime->format('h:i A');
```

To group them according to your preference is not super trivial to automate, you will have to group them by day, time and number of occurences.

Answer (score 0):

In your first question how to get day by `DayId`, you can do like this:

```
$mapDay = [
    0 => "Sunday",
    1 => "Monday",
    2 => "Tuesday",
    3 => "Wednesday",
    4 => "Thursday",
    5 => "Friday",
    6 => "Saturday"
];

$array = array_map(function($item) use ($mapDay) {
    $item['DayId'] = $mapDay[$item['DayId']];
    return $item;
}, $array);
```

and this will not hamper your existing array structure;

In your second question how to transform your `StartTime` and `EndTime` to this format Sat, Sun: 08:30 AM - 07:00 PM. You can do like this:

```
function transformDateToString($startTime, $endTime) {
    $start = strtotime($startTime);
    $end = strtotime($endTime);

    $startDay = date('D', strtotime($start));
    $endDay = date('D', strtotime($end));

    $startHour = date('h:i A', strtotime($start));
    $endHour = date('h:i A', strtotime($end));

    return sprintf("%s,%s %s - %s", $startDay, $endDay, $startHour, $endHour);
}
```

Hopefully, it will solve your problem.